# Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" while trying to connect with oracledb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oracle, node-oracledb

So I was just trying to connect the oracle database with node.js (simple connection nothing fancy) and I am getting this error:

```
util.js:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js (util.js:39:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js (oracledb.js:22:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/oracledb/index.js (index.js:1:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

I am not sure if I even doing this correct as I just had look at the documentation don't know if there is a mistake or not. I am sure the oracle is running even SQL query were working fine (on oracle 21c) and i have all the modules required.

My index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const oracledb = require("oracledb");
try {
  let connection = oracledb.getConnection({
    user: "SYS",
    password: "yc",
    connectString: "YC_Database",
  });
  console.log("connection successful");
} catch (err) {
  console.log("can't connect");
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Here are a couple of comments: You're missing an `await` before the call to `oracledb.connection()` - check the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/connect.js).  Secondly, if you're using Webpack, check https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1156#issuecomment-598017250 for configuration info

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for my issue but I am unable to find the fix.

Comment: You'll have to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a new fresh react app that I created this is the only code that I have and if you want I can give you the code for the webpack.config or util.js where the error is showing but I haven't changed anything or add anything.